# Yarn workspace with both ts and js

Tags: javascript, typescript, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I want to create yarn workspace for both ts and js modules. For example main root workspace will contains js code and other two workspaces that are inside of our root will contain ts and js code. Is it possible to set up yarn workspace with both js and ts?